# Where to get schemas for log events for windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, event-log

For example, "Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" source contains bunch of power related data, for example, event with id 507 looks like this:

```
<Event
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" />
        <EventID>507</EventID>
        <Version>9</Version>
        <Level>4</Level>
        <Task>158</Task>
        <Opcode>0</Opcode>
        <Keywords>0x8000000000000604</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-07-09T11:29:26.1076974Z" />
        <EventRecordID>6722</EventRecordID>
        <Correlation />
        <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="17512" />
        <Channel>System</Channel>
        <Computer>DESKTOP-3CI3S1R</Computer>
        <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data Name="EnergyDrain">10879</Data>
        <Data Name="ActiveResidencyInUs">20185268</Data>
        <Data Name="NonDripsTimeActivatedInUs">93507145</Data>
        <Data Name="FirstDripsEntryInUs">0</Data>
        <Data Name="DripsResidencyInUs">0</Data>
        <Data Name="DurationInUs">20185268</Data>
        <Data Name="DripsTransitions">0</Data>
        <Data Name="FullChargeCapacityRatio">96</Data>
        <Data Name="AudioPlaying">false</Data>
        <Data Name="Reason">31</Data>
        <Data Name="AudioPlaybackInUs">0</Data>
        <Data Name="NonActivatedCpuInUs">498137</Data>
        <Data Name="PowerStateAc">false</Data>
        <Data Name="HwDripsResidencyInUs">0</Data>
        <Data Name="ExitLatencyInUs">14</Data>
        <Data Name="DisconnectedStandby">true</Data>
        <Data Name="AoAcCompliantNic">true</Data>
        <Data Name="NonAttributedCpuInUs">0</Data>
        <Data Name="ModernSleepEnabledActionsBitmask">0</Data>
        <Data Name="ModernSleepAppliedActionsBitmask">0</Data>
        <Data Name="LidOpenState">true</Data>
        <Data Name="ExternalMonitorConnectedState">false</Data>
        <Data Name="ScenarioInstanceId">141</Data>
        <Data Name="IsCsSessionInProgressOnExit">false</Data>
        <Data Name="BatteryRemainingCapacityOnExit">45433</Data>
        <Data Name="BatteryFullChargeCapacityOnExit">58003</Data>
        <Data Name="ScenarioInstanceIdV2">139</Data>
        <Data Name="BootId">11</Data>
        <Data Name="InputSuppressionActionCount">0</Data>
        <Data Name="NonResiliencyTimeInUs">18446744073630679738</Data>
        <Data Name="ResiliencyDripsTimeInUs">28910641341</Data>
        <Data Name="ResiliencyHwDripsTimeInUs">0</Data>
        <Data Name="GdiOnTime">0</Data>
        <Data Name="DwmSyncFlushTime">0</Data>
        <Data Name="MonitorPowerOnTime">2674780</Data>
        <Data Name="SleepEntered">true</Data>
        <Data Name="ScreenOffEnergyCapacityAtStart">45494</Data>
        <Data Name="ScreenOffEnergyCapacityAtEnd">45494</Data>
        <Data Name="ScreenOffDurationInUs">2128949</Data>
        <Data Name="SleepEnergyCapacityAtStart">45494</Data>
        <Data Name="SleepEnergyCapacityAtEnd">45433</Data>
        <Data Name="SleepDurationInUs">18078525</Data>
        <Data Name="ScreenOffFullEnergyCapacityAtStart">58003</Data>
        <Data Name="ScreenOffFullEnergyCapacityAtEnd">58003</Data>
        <Data Name="SleepFullEnergyCapacityAtStart">58003</Data>
        <Data Name="SleepFullEnergyCapacityAtEnd">58003</Data>
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

Where I can get schema for this particular event and other possible events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Where I can get schema for this particular event and other possible events?

You can see the schema at [[MS-EVEN6]: Event | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-even6/8c61aef7-bd4b-4edb-8dfd-3c9a7537886b):

```
<xs:schema 
 targetNamespace=
 "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"
 elementFormDefault=
 "qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:evt=
 "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
```

...

Alternatively you can download the Windows SDK:

> The Windows SDK includes the schema in the `\Include\Event.xsd` file.

Source: [Event Schema - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/eventschema-schema)

Comment: Looks like that msdn links does not contain list of fields per-event in EventData field of event... For me that list is the most important part of event.

Comment: @crashtua I don't think that list will be available and it's not what the question asked for. The question asked for the schema. That was what I answered.